# Creating A Gallery App of Photos and Videos in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I am currently developing a camera app in android using camerax and camera controller. For the UI part, I am using Jetpack Compose.

I want to have a button in my camera app, which when clicked, leads to a screen of all photos and videos arranged in column of two or three ordered by the date that they were took.

I tried to develop a small gallery screen using Scaffold only for photos by converting the images to bitmaps. The problem is that, whenever the app is closed, the images are also getting deleted. It is not getting saved to the device media. **[Refer the below code takePhoto function]**. I know the reason, why it is not getting saved to the device media, as I have not given the location but, If I give the media location, I am not able to see the images that I am not able to see the images in the small scaffold gallery screen that I have created. We are not allowed to use both **ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() and ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback()**

```
private fun takePhoto(
    context: Context,
    controller: LifecycleCameraController,
    onPhotoTaken: (Bitmap) -> Unit,
    contentResolver: ContentResolver
) {controller.takePicture(
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image)

                val matrix = Matrix().apply {
                    postRotate(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())
                }
                val rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    image.toBitmap(),
                    0,
                    0,
                    image.width,
                    image.height,
                    matrix,
                    false
                )

                onPhotoTaken(rotatedBitmap)


            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                super.onError(exception)
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Photo capture failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Below is the gallery screen function

```
fun GalleryBottom(
    bitmaps: List<Bitmap>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    if(bitmaps.isEmpty()) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(16.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text("There are no photos yet", color = Color.Black)
        }
    } else {
        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            verticalItemSpacing = 16.dp,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            modifier = modifier
        ) {
            items(bitmaps) { bitmap ->
                Image(
                    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Video Capture Function, These videos are getting saved in the device media but not getting displayed in the gallery screen, as they are not converted into bitmaps **I am not able to find a logic for that**

```
private fun captureVideo(controller: LifecycleCameraController, context: Context, contentResolver: ContentResolver) {

    if (recording != null) {
        recording?.stop()
        recording = null
        return
    }
    val name = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS", Locale.UK)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/AirPic")
        }
    }

    val mediaStoreOutputOptions = MediaStoreOutputOptions
        .Builder(contentResolver, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        .setContentValues(contentValues)
        .build()


    recording = controller.startRecording(
        mediaStoreOutputOptions,
        AudioConfig.create(true),
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
    ) { event ->
        when (event) {
            is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                if (event.hasError()) {
                    recording?.close()
                    recording = null

                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Video capture failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("Video", "Captured Video")
    }
}
```

Kindly help me with this one, where I can access the photos and videos from the below location and create a screen of gallery consisting of photos and videos present in that location.

**For Videos**

```
val name = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS", Locale.UK)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/AirPic")
        }
    }
```

**For Photos**

```
val name = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS", Locale.UK)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/AirPic")
        }
    }
```